# Eclipse Display View is throwing error

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

all. Amy requirement is checking one exception condition(whether the message is alright or not). For that, I have thrown exception keeping my code in debug mode.

I have written following expression, right click after selecting the expression, execute.

```
throw new NullPointerException();
```

Eclipse is showing

```
Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
        Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Show us an [mcve] We can't tell what is wrong from just one line, you probably have it in the wrong place.

Comment: The evaluation usually run in the context of the breakpoint you're hitting. Could the syntax error be on the file where breakpoint is located?

Comment: pseudo code is like following
`try{
 statements or method call;
} catch(Exception) {
  Error message;
}`
I have placed the break point when the control is on statement or method call. 

There is no syntactical error in the code as it is building with maven without any error.

I am using Eclipse Neon and Java 8

Answer (score 3):

Wrap in curly brackets and press Ctrl+U. Should work in neon.

```
{throw new NullPointerException();}
```